# How to create different facebook notification when inviting friends in android app?

Tags: android, notifications, facebook-sdk-3.1, facebook-invite

I had successfully made my android app invite friends ;  refer to :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0

```
WebDialog requestsDialog = new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(ctx,s, params).build();
requestsDialog.show();
```

The Notification I sent to friends appear to be: "**APPNAME:SENDER sent you requests.**"

But there are one case that i am not creating a game and i just want the invitation to invite friends to try the apps.

Apparently there are not only one type of facebook invite we can receive.

These are few notification i can see in my android facebook

> 1. APPNAME: SENDER sent you requests (this is result what developers.facebook document guide lead to)
> 2. SENDER invited you to play APPNAME.
> 3. **SENDER invited you to try APPNAME.** (this is what i intend to get)

**How can I generate 3rd type of notification in my android app using java?**